# Issue with overlapping text: iOS7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I normally post source code and examples of UI but I think its more related to an iOS7 change and I cant see it being a code bug (yet). I would have to post so much code and UI that it would be counter productive. So here is my best non-visual description:

Since upgrading a project to iOS7 I am finding that if I put call to change a `UILabel` or calling `setText` of a `UIButton` in a `ViewDidAppear` or `ViewWillAppear` it puts the new text right on top of the old text.

Since developing for iOS I have never had to do anything different. If I do this:

`lblMyHours.text = @"12";`

It shouldnt just throw that on top of my existing label.

This especially  happens inside of a `UITableView` where I have created an iVar for a `UILabel` thats in a `UITableViewCell`. If a user makes an adjustment to a value after clicking on a cell (it takes them to a detail screen to edit), when I pop back I have it recalculate in `ViewDidAppear`. In that recalculating I am resetting a label like the above. But it doesnt clear out the old.

Comment: Aren't you adding a new label on top of the old one every time you return a new cell?

Comment: Oh!!! I never thought of that. Ok I am away from my mac right now but I will have to look at it. Its been driving me crazy but you are right that it could actually be instantiating a new object and putting it right on top of the old...

Comment: @Guilherme please add this as an answer so I can accept it. It was silly that I didnt realize that I was actually adding a new one on top of it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be adding a new label every time you return a new cell.
You should just replace the text of the current label instead.

Comment: Because it was so helpful to me, you might even get a bounty reward for it, just checking up on the correct way to do it.

Comment: ok I have to wait 24 hours to award it, but you will have an extra 50 pts tomorrow! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to achieve this, one you are already doing and as @Guilherme rightly pointed out. The other way is to create a custom tableview cell and put the UILabel property in there. As for the viewDidAppear scenario, you can create a uilabel in ther .h file (in the @interface declaration) and then initialize it in ViewDidLoad method and simple use in ViewDidAppear method without having to declare it again.

I would suggest that you follow the way I described for ViewDidAppear issue, and for the UITableView issue, search for UILabels in subview of the cell everytime cellForRowAtIndex method is called and remove it from the subview, something like this before adding a new label

```
for(UIView *view in cell.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
         [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.